# Duplicate direct dependencies in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I deliberately wanted to see if maven allows duplicate direct dependencies (i.e. non transitive dependencies) as it uses dependency mediation to resolve the conflicting transitive dependencies.

I wrote this is in my pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
```

I was surprised to see, it is picking 4.10 version instead of 4.11. What could be reason for this ?

---

I will add more details that shows it violates [dependency mediation principle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) too. Here is output of `mvn dependency:tree` for only standalone junit 4.10 version VS standalone junit 4.11 version:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ PracticeMaven ---
[INFO] org.example:PracticeMaven:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test

[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ PracticeMaven ---
[INFO] org.example:PracticeMaven:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

If you see there is a conflict with `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core` when we mention both junit in pom.xml. It should have chosen `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3` as 4.11 is mentioned first. But it does not. It choses `junit 4.10` and `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1`.

I am using latest Apache Maven 3.6.3.

Comment: First it should produce a warning....

Comment: @khmarbaise , correct. It does produce a warning - `[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: junit:junit:jar -> version 4.11 vs 4.10 @ line 30, column 17`

Comment: This is already a hint that in your build is something really wrong...which should be fixed...

Answer (score 1):

Why were you surprised to see this?

It is probably always taking the last one. Avoid this if possible (the only use case I could see is to alter a dependency that was defined in a parent POM).

Comment: I was surprised as according to dependency mediation, where it chooses the one with shortest path to achieve it. In case of equal paths, first one as generated by direct dependency will get priority. *If* we extend this principle for resolving of direct dependency in case of duplicates , then 4.11 should be chosen. But that was not the result.

Comment: Ok, do you have a source for this?

Comment: From [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) , `"nearest definition" means that the version used will be the closest one to your project....`

Comment: But your two dependencies are both on the same level, so none of them is nearer than the other.

Comment: It is written at top of it - `Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, the first declaration wins.`

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin Thank you. I think you are right that your "experiment" and the documentation say different things.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how accurate this information still is, but:

> When declaring a "normal" version such as 3.8.2 for Junit, internally
>   this is represented as "allow any-thing, but prefer 3.8.2." This means
>   that when a conflict is detected, Maven is allowed to use the
>   conflict algorithms to choose the best version.  If you specify
>   [3.8.2], it means that only 3.8.2 will be used andnothing else.  If
>   somewhere else there is a dependency that specifies [3.8.1], you would
>   get a buildfailure telling you of the conflict. We point this out to
>   make you aware of the option, but use it sparingly and only when really
>   needed. The preferred way to resolve this is via dependencyManagement

Source: [Maven: The Complete Reference](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/pdf/mvnref-pdf.pdf), page 35

So, usually given a version without a range (using round or square brackets) is just hint what you like to use, not something Maven has to obey.